# Avconv warning while downloading YouTube video

Tags: kubuntu, avconv, youtube-dl

I received this warning:

```
Your copy of avconv is outdated, 
update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
```

while downloading a YouTube video with `youtube-dl -f 137+140`. I am using kubuntu 14.04.

What should I do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: `.. update avconv to version 10-0 ...`

Comment: I think it's just `sudo apt-get update` then (when it finishes) `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To answer OP's question the way he wants it:

```
# before
$ avconv |& grep \ version | awk '{print $3}'
9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1,

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/libav-11 && sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libav-tools

# after
$ avconv |& grep \ version | awk '{print $3}'
11.3-6:11.3-1~trusty,
```

Alternatively, can `avconv -version` to get `avconv` latest version

Answer (score 22):

By default youtube-dl uses `avconv`, but you can tell it to use `ffmpeg` instead.

Then use youtube-dl with `--prefer-ffmpeg` flag, e.g.:

```
youtube-dl -f 137+140 --prefer-ffmpeg <url>
```

To avoid typing that flag everytime, you can put it in the [configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#configuration).

Comment: This didn't help on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 box, but upgrading as suggested by @user35186 (see below) helped. The hint with the config file is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error message, your version of `avconv` is outdated, and needs to be updated.

If you installed `avconv` through a package manager (such as `apt-get` or `synaptic`), you can use the following commands to update `avonv`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**sudo apt-get update** updates your local index of software in the Ubuntu repositories. This allows `sudo apt-get upgrade` to detect if any updates are available.

**sudo apt-get upgrade** is responisble for actually upgrading any outdated software.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your own version of libav

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev build-essential nasm pkg-config
wget https://libav.org/releases/libav-10.7.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo cp avconv avprobe avserver /usr/local/bin/
```

This especially works for older distros which can't pick the latest versions of libav. 
Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=197316