# unable to download 480p format using youtube-dl

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download `480p` format youtube video using `youtube-dl` using

```
youtube-dl -f 135+141 --prefer-ffmpeg <url>
```

and i get the following error and it failed to mix audio and video

```
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated, update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
```

I have tried the solution given in [avconv version and youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645462/avconv-version-and-youtube-dl) by `mchid` and [Avconv warning while downloading YouTube video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563245/avconv-warning-while-downloading-youtube-video) by `user35186`, still the problem has not been solved and now it shows

```
WARNING: Your copy of ffmpeg is outdated, update ffmpeg to version 1.0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
ERROR: Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c'.
```

How do I solve this and download 480p format video ?

**Other Details:-**

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

youtube-dl 2016.02.04

ffmpeg version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

It involves a reasonable amount of work but one method would be:

1. Install the latest FFmpeg following [these directions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). This will not interfere with any system FFmpeg or avconv installations.
2. Make sure you have the latest `youtube-dl` by running:

   ```
   sudo youtube-dl --update
   ```
3. Point `youtube-dl` to your new, local copy of FFmpeg:

   ```
   youtube-dl -f 135+141 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location $HOME/bin <url>
   ```
4. Decrease your commandline complexity by adding your preferences to your `$HOME/.config/youtube-dl.conf` file as:

   ```
   --prefer-ffmpeg
   --ffmpeg-location $HOME/bin
   ```

It is a little hassle but once setup correctly you should have no further issues...

Comment: this did not work.

Comment: Certainly works at this end :). Which part failed?